# Have registered class on admin, but it doesn't show up

Tags: django, django-admin

This is my admin.py. I have created the file by myself and don't know if I need to register it somewhere in settings.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Athlete

admin.site.register(Athlete)
```

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Athlete(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Both files are in my project folder. I don't have any apps. When I go to `url/admin/` I expect to be able to create and edit athletes, but I can only edit groups and users.

What more do I need to do to make Athletes editable in admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your module into settings INSTALLED_APPS list. Probably you forgot it (as you guess in your comment).

Comment: I haven't created any app, so I don't think I have any app to register. I executed django-admin startproject mysitedjango and haven't created any app after that. I have all my files in mysitedjango/mysitedjango/. Maybe this is my first mistake, should I have created an app?

Comment: Yes, creating an app is a good practice. It will allow you to reuse that feature. If not, just add 'mysitedjango' in apps. Maybe it will work.